# How to use Rank over partition by in Solr Streaming

Tags: solr, rank

How to use Rank over partition by in Solr Streaming.

Table A (city, streetname), need a query as below having rank 2, 
city1 - streetname1, streetname2
city2 - streetname1, streetname2
city3 - streetname1, streetname2

Is there any fucntion to support the above?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you want to do. Could you add more examples? Solr Streaming Expressions doesn't really rank stuff, but you can do that through function calls - but the original queries and sort statements (in SE) might be what you're looking for?

Comment: Thanks for the response, the requirement is to fetch top N records for each group from the collection using streaming feature.

Comment: tried this query, doent seem to work  => search(collection1, q=*:*,group=true,group.sort="groupbyfield",group.field="groupbyfield",group.limit=10)

Comment: The `reduce` and `top` functions might be what you want, which you can apply to the stream from `search`. The `search` source does not accept all the parameters that a regular query accepts as far as I know.

Comment: That did the trick, Thanks MatsLindh!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `reduce` and `top` functions to implement what you want. These functions work on the stream returned from `search` and allow you to create the same functionality as `group` would have in a regular query.

> `reduce`
>
> The reduce function wraps an internal stream and groups tuples by common fields.
>
> Each tuple group is operated on as a single block by a pluggable reduce operation. The group operation provided with Solr implements distributed grouping functionality. The group operation also serves as an example reduce operation that can be referred to when building custom reduce operations.
>
> *The reduce function relies on the sort order of the underlying stream. Accordingly the sort order of the underlying stream must be aligned with the group by field.*
>
> `top`
>
> The top function wraps a streaming expression and re-orders the tuples. The top function emits only the top N tuples in the new sort order. The top function re-orders the underlying stream so the sort criteria does not have to match up with the underlying stream.

The `search` stream source does not accept all the parameters that a regular query accepts - but have its own subset of allowed parameters:

> `search` Parameters
>
> `collection`: (Mandatory) the collection being searched.
>
> `q`: (Mandatory) The query to perform on the Solr index.
>
> `fl`: (Mandatory) The list of fields to return.
>
> `sort`: (Mandatory) The sort criteria.
>
> `zkHost`: Only needs to be defined if the collection being searched is found in a different `zkHost` than the local stream handler.
>
> `qt`: Specifies the query type, or request handler, to use. Set this to /export to work with large result sets. The default is `/select`.
>
> `rows`: (Mandatory with the `/select` handler) The rows parameter specifies how many rows to return. This parameter is only needed with the `/select` handler (which is the default) since the `/export` handler always returns all rows.
>
> `partitionKeys`: Comma delimited list of keys to partition the search results by. To be used with the parallel function for parallelizing operations across worker nodes. See the parallel function for details.